# How to retrieve only those object and its related model which passes the required criteria in laravel4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three tables: users, departments and designations

I have created corresponding model for 'users', 'designations' and 'departments' table.

Relationship between table is:

> User model
>
> ```
> public function department(){
>   return $this->belongsTo('Department');
> }
> ```
>
> > ```
> > public function designation(){
> >   return $this->belongsTo('Designation');
> > }
> > ```

--

> Department model
>
> ```
> public function users(){
>   return $this->hasMany('User');
> }
> ```

--

> Designation model
>
> ```
> public function users(){
>   return $this->hasMany('User');
> }
> ```

Now, how would I query (in an eloquent way) to retrieve all the users that belongs to only specified department (say, 'account' department only).

I tried eager loading as well, but since there were two models that have to be fed with, it was more confusing.

I have a code as below, but now working. Help me to find the mistake

```
$users = new User;
$users = $users->department()->where('dept_code', '=', 'account')->get();
return View::make('staffs', compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

#### 1. From the `Department` side

```
$department = Department::where('dept_code', 'account')->first();
$users = $department->users;
```

#### 2. From the `User` side using [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

```
$users = User::whereHas('department', function($q){
    $q->where('dept_code', 'account');
})->get();
```

(Of course you can also use them like `$users = new User; $users->where(`, but I prefer the static call syntax so I use them in my examples)

Comment: yeah it works. But the number of times its been executing query is quite high (I can live with that for now, since application is not that big). What if I want to do eager loading. I read laravel documentation, it only shows the example where a single related model can be loaded. But not more than one related model. (I dont know if my question is clear or not). In this case I have to load two models: Department and Designation along with User model. @lukasgeiter

Comment: Adding `with('department', 'designation')` to the second query in my answer should be sufficient. I didn't know you needed the actual data of the relations...

Answer (score 0):

You define a relationship with the constant. Like this:

**User model**

```
public function department(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Department');
}

public function accounts_department(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Department')->where('dept_code', 'account');
}
```

Then you use it like this

```
$all_users = new User;
$all_users = $all_users->department()->get();

$account_only_users = new User;
$account_only_users = $account_only_users ->accounts_department()->get();
```

Comment: didnt know that restriction can can be applied within the relationship defining method.